# C: Function passing array input

Tags: c

i have a beginner question about function in C, say I have a array of pointers to linked list and I want to write a function to add a pointer of a node to the array:

```
void addhash(int value,struct node ** arr[]){
    struct node *p =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p->value=10;
    arr[value]=&p;
};
```

Is this the correct way to define the function? when I run this in main, the bucket that I tried to add a node to is somehow still NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr[value]=&p` is effectively returning a pointer to a local variable, which is never a valid thing to do. Local variables do not exist after the function returns. It looks like what you want is to declare the parameter as `node *arr[]` and change that line to `arr[value]=p`. That will correctly save a pointer to the memory you allocated for the node.

You may also want to think about whether it makes more sense to have the function just allocate and initialize the `node` structure and return that, at which point the caller can add it to the array.

Comment: I defined my array with struct node **hashtable[10000];

Comment: so I think I should instead define it like struct node *hashtable[10000]; and rewrite my function accordingly then, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In your exemple you are not adding the pointer of node but you are adding a pointeur of a pointeur to the node.
the pointeur to the node is p if you save the adresse of p then you are saving the adresse of the pointer. we have p is a local variable so it will dislocate when we return from the function.

Rule: never try to save adresse of a local variable and use it outside the function that declare this variable.

```
void addhash(int value,struct node * arr[]){
struct node *p =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
p->value=10;
arr[value]=p;
};
```

I hope that I have answered your question